# Text extraction from PDF in UNICODE

Tags: c++, pdf, unicode, zlib

I need to extract text from pdf files and I found this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7056/Code-to-extract-plain-text-from-a-PDF-file) which takes every text stream from pdf file and decompresses it.. But I also need to extract the text in Unicode so I tried to adapt my code so it can use wchar_t characters. Only problem is that zlib accepts only one byte at a time for decompressing.. And my wchar_t doesn't have 1 byte per 1 character.

So, is there a way I can work things out here? :)

Comment: The article you have makes many assumptions, one of them being that all text is encoded using some standard encoding.  This generally is not the case and every used font has its own encoding. Thus, it is not merely a question of bytes versus wide chars but of considering font information. The article you found completely ignores them.

Comment: For all my pdf files I want to extract text from it works perfectly so if you can, help me with my question about bytes and Zlib. :)

Comment: If *it works perfectly*, what is your issue? Ok, teasing aside, PDF content streams containing characters requiring you to use wide chars don't use standard encodings. Thus, they cannot be handled as naively as the code from that article you found does.

Comment: So is there a way I can use wide chars as buffer for Zlib?

Comment: If you cast it to `byte[]`, sure.

Comment: I did that from the beginning and Zlib produces Z_DATA_ERROR..

Comment: But you said *it works perfectly*... what are you trying to achieve, what have you tried, and what went wrong?

Comment: It works perfectly with char*.. but I need wchar_t* for some unicode characters.. When I'm using wchar_t* it gives me Z_DATA_ERROR. Thanks for support, by the way.. :)

Comment: What you get after inflating is only by chance coherent according to some encoding. You should use the decoded char array and use the string encoding information from the pdf specification to translate that array into actual characters in a wide char array. That been said, for which Unicode  characters do you need that change? If you are lucky, the situation is not as bad as i fear it is.

Comment: I need it for "ş", "ţ" and "ă"...

Comment: I'm afraid those characters are not contained in one of the standard PDF Latin Encodings, cf. annex D.2 in [the PDF specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf). Thus, the naive approach from that article you found will not work. To understand the necessary conversions, read section 9.10 *Extraction of Text Content* in the PDF specification.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15273013/1729265) to get an impression where one has to look when extracting text and why even then one can be misled.